# Two-way MANOVA appropriate in this case?

Tags: self-study, experiment-design, manova

I'm having a problem with an analysis that's part of a statistics course. We were handed out a dataset (total n=456) that's supposed to measure the impact of background graphics on player experience in a specific video game genre. Background graphics were either high or low detail as well as animated or not animated.

But there are five treatments, since they added one with no background graphics at all (thus, no animation either), considered as being some kind of a control group. Also it's a between subjects design with independent groups. The number of observations per group is around 90.

I'm interested in main effects as well as the interaction of detail and animation on player experience. Plus I wanted to include the control group to see, if the presence of background graphics does matter at all. Since there are three continous dependent variables representing the construct of player experience, I figured I could conduct a two-way MANOVA.

The treatment variable consists of five numbers representing each treatment. So I recoded it into two new nominal variables, namely graphics (high, low, none) and animation (animated, not animated). The data met all the necessary assumptions (normality, homogenity, etc.) so I ran the MANOVA in SPSS.

My problem is: the way I created the two independent variables leads to six cells, but I only have 5 groups (since there obviously can't be a "no background graphics / animated" group). SPSS only reports on those 5 groups, as I expected.

Would it still be valid to report the results even though there's one cell missing?

Or should I look for another way to analyze the data? I thought of doing a one-way MANOVA (followed by a post-hoc test) using the original treatment variable as the independent variable to check for difference to the control group. After that I would split the dataset in "control/not control" and conduct the two-way MANOVA only on those not in the control group using the variables detail (high/low) and animation (animated/not animated).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! I couldn't find anything helpful using google. 
Sorry for any mistake concerning grammar, I'm not a native speaker :)

Comment: Not clear why you ran a MANOVA here. You stated you had only one dependent var Player Experience. Is that correct?